# Can you access global JS vars from within an Iframe hosted on S3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, amazon-s3, global-variables

I have my site loading an iFrame whose source is an S3 file tree.

I would like to call my parent global namespace : `window.app.events`

Is that possible? If its not possible, any tips to somehow share data between an iFrame hosted on S3 to its parent window?

Answer (score 1):

You can't read from frames running on another domain.

You *can* send data between frames of different domains using [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

http://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage